# Using FSharp.Data

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I'm new to F# (but not C# fwiw), and I'm trying to follow the tutorial here:

http://www.ojdevelops.com/2016/03/web-scraping-with-f.html

I've learned that #r cannot be in class files, but must be in script files, so in a new F# Console Application template, I created Script.fsx and pasted in from the tutorial:

```
#r "FSharp.Data"

open FSharp.Data

let googleUrl = "http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=FSharp.Data"
let doc = HtmlDocument.Load(googleUrl)
```

I have also added via NuGet package manager FSharp.Data and I see it in the Packages folder. I have tried different variations of the "link" to the FSharp.Data package, including the one used in the tutorial (#r "../../../bin/FSharp.Data.dll") but always get "Assembly reference was not found or is invalid". I can reach FSharp.Data but only the UnitSystems namespace, which is apparently a part of FSharp.Core and not what I want for HtmlDocument.

I experience the same issues whether using Visual Studio for Mac with Mono or Visual Studio 2015/2017 on Windows 10.

Comment: Simple answer is to use an absolute path rather than relative

Comment: You need to specify a correct path to `FSharp.Data.dll` relative to where the script file is located.

Comment: That seems like a "more complicated than it should be" solution... I wouldn't have to do that with a C# project, for example. But that did it. It's just that reduces the portability of the code, no? Now I would have to change that path if I ever move the project, even to a different folder on the same computer.

Comment: @jimmyco2008 in C# you usually don't do scripts (maybe in 2017 it's possible). This is not usually an issue because the path to Fsharp.Data would be specified like this: `#r "..\packages\FSharp.Data\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll"` .  So it is indeed a relative path.  I do move the project folders around, and maintain slightly different folder structure on different PCs.  And  you can use an `#I` directive  to specify the folder. Probably `__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__`  won't work directly here.  Also, no need for the `#r` if you just use and fs file and compile, you would just add the reference in VS.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info! I do see that VS tries to find a relative-path-referenced package in default locations within the project, I just wasn't able to nail the correct relative path. I'll give it another go. #I sounds like it's the better way to go in general, even as a "just in case you end up using another package".